# IIS 8 401.3 with ACL and static content

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm having a problem with IIS and ACL's.

I have configured an MVC application under a dedicated AppPool. The apppool runs under the ApplicationPoolIdentity (which in my case would be the user IIS AppPool\accountinfo.local = the same name as my website).

I gave full control to this user on the root folder and made sure that the permissions are inherited.

When I access the home page it runs fine and I can access it. However, when I try to access my static content, which is in a subfolder (Content/Site.css) I get an error 401.3.

I have made sure that permissions are inherited and if I go to effective permissions I can see that this user does have full control.

I have enabled failed request tracing and also security auditing but I don't get any log files, nor any events in the event viewer.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

OK, I got it.

Apparently requests for static content don't go through the applicationIdentity but through the standard IUSR account.

Once I gave this user read permissions on the folder, it started working.

Learnt something new today.

Comment: So adding IUSR worked, but I don't believe I had IUSR before and there is another website that doesn't have IUSR and I can pull up static content.  I verified IIS is using IUSR for both, so there must be some other setting somewhere

Comment: You can also change the `Anonymous Authentication Credentials` to `Application pool identity` as described [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831515.aspx#Step3)

Answer (score 7):

When using anonymous authentication in IIS, static content is accessed (and served) by the "Anonymous user identity."  By default, this is set to the specific built-in user account "IUSR" - thus why granting permissions for that user fixes the problem (as mentioned in [Kenneth's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16379621/861565)).

If you prefer not to use the IUSR account for whatever reason, you can change the "Anonymous user identity" for the web site in IIS by doing the following:

1. Go to the site in IIS and double click "Authentication" in the feature pane

[image: screenshot of IIS feature pane with authentication highlighted]

2. Right-click "Anonymous Authentication" and select "Application pool identity" to use your app pool identity (or you can set a different specific user than IUSR by clicking the "Set" button)

[image: screenshot of edit anonymous authentication credentials dialog]

The process is also documented in this Microsoft Docs article:

[Build a Static Website on IIS - Step 3: Configure Anonymous Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/orphan-topics/ws.11/hh831515(v=ws.11)#step-3-configure-anonymous-authentication)

I'll reproduce one significant reason you may choose to change the anonymous authentication identity, which is called out in that article:

> If you use the IUSR account, you grant anonymous users all the internal network access associated with that account.