# Getting a 401.3 Unauthorized error when accessing the default document without specifying a filename

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have an IIS site and I put a default document (default.aspx) on the root of the site.  If I browse to mysite.com/default.aspx it will work.  However, if browse to mysite.com, I get a 401.3 - unauthorized error.

The default document is already set in iis.  I also tried setting system.webServer...defaultDocument in the web.config and that did nothing.

HTTP Error 401.3 - Unauthorized

You do not have permission to view this directory or page because of the access control list (ACL) configuration or encryption settings for this resource on the Web server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IIS 8 401.3 with ACL and static content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16379529/iis-8-401-3-with-acl-and-static-content)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that default.aspx is the default file in IIS.  Sometimes the default file is index.html. My guess is that the index file will be served if you add it. Check the web site settings for your web site on IIS.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to open the IIS console application and locate your web site's default document to see the default.aspx is inside it.

[image]

[image]

Then I suggest you could chekc your web.config file to make sure there are no url rewrite url is enabled in your application.